# How to deduplicate reoccuring strings in the same line?

Tags: bash, shell

I know how to remove reoccurring lines in a text file with Linux using sort and uniq, but I'm unable to find a method to remove reoccurring strings in the same line.

for example:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline

BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-137-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg--01-lv--root ro cdgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 maybe-ubiquity transparent_hugepage=never LANG=en_US.UTF-8 cdgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 maybe-ubiquity transparent_hugepage=never LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

How would I go about removing the reoccurring string 'transparent_hugepage=never' so that it only prints once?

Answer (score 2):

I would harness `awk` for the task, iterating over the fields while outputting the unique ones:

```bash
awk '
    {
        delete seen
        seen[$1]++
        printf "%s", $1  
        for ( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ )
            if ( !seen[$i]++ )
                printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
        print ""
    }
'
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You're right; I fixed it along the reset of `seen`. Now the code is a little long ^^

Comment: I figured you just overlooked it and had waited a while, then posted the other answer. Deleted now you got it fixed. I would have missed the `delete seen` anyway ...